# How could MACUSA exist in 1693 or be in Washington in 1777?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, jk-rowling, pottermore

Two brief excerpts from [*The Magical Congress of the United States of America (MACUSA)* By J.K. Rowling](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/macusa) on Pottermore state the following:

- > The Magical Congress of the United States of America, known to American witches and wizards by the abbreviation MACUSA (commonly pronounced as: Mah – cooz – ah) was created in **1693**, following the introduction of the International Statute of Wizarding Secrecy.
- > It was in Washington that President Elizabeth McGilliguddy presided over the infamous ‘Country or Kind?’ debate of **1777**.

How is this possible since the "United States of America" was [not founded until 1776](https://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/congress-renames-the-nation-united-states-of-america) with the writing of the Declaration of Independence AND Washington, DC was [not founded until 1790](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/arts-culture/a-brief-history-of-pierre-lenfant-and-washington-dc-39487784/?no-ist)?

---

More to the point how did a team of writers, advisors, editors, etc. not notice this glaring error? **Have any comments been made by Rowling or her team regarding this?**

Comment: Perhaps JKR is so bad at maths that she thinks 1777 > 1790.

Comment: Or perhaps she's too British to know anything about American history. (Wait, what history? You lot only have a few hundred years of it! :-P )

Comment: Must have been a hell of a lot of Seers among those American wizards.

Comment: Oh dear :( As they say on the internet: smh

Comment: Is there more than one Washington in the US?

Comment: @Valorum there are plenty but the naming convention started with a person... who was born in 1732!

Comment: @Skooba - I mean, was it definitely Washington DC or could it have been Washington, Idaho or Washington, New York or whatever?

Comment: @Valorum I *highly* doubt it. Remember there were only 13 colonies and all the places are named after George Washington, but to make sure I have asked a sister stack for help http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/33244/was-any-city-town-place-named-washington-prior-to-1790

Comment: @Skooba - And I've answered. I can find at least two contemporaneous ***Washington***'s in the US prior to 1777.

Comment: The US was not founded in 1776 with the writing of the Declaration (though that was important), but in 1788 when a sufficient number of states had ratified the Constitution.

Comment: I removed the 2016 tag until a consensus is reached on meta.

Comment: The USA as a term was invented in 1776, though

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Probably for the same reason MACUSA is called MACUSA in 1693](http://hellogiggles.com/pottermore-mistake-jk-rowling/), over 100 years before the United States became the United States, and why [Dudley had a Playstation before Playstations existed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18265/how-could-dudley-have-wrecked-his-playstation-if-the-playstation-didnt-exist-yet)!

**Poor or no research to validate the numbers. AKA Author error.**

J.K. Rowling admits to making the occasional continuity error:

> "As obsessive fans will tell you, I do slip up! Several classrooms move floors mysteriously between books and these are the least serious continuity errors! Most of the fansites will point you in the direction of my mistakes. But the essentials remain consistent from book to book because the story has been plotted for a long time and it is clear in my mind."

Accordingly, I would like to know for how long J.K. Rowling has had Pottermore planned out.

As well, we all know [J.K. Rowling is bad at math](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/140363/what-is-jk-rowling-bad-at).

As of this writing, I cannot find any comments on this matter by J.K. Rowling or her staff.

<sub>I answered this question solely to use [HelloGiggles.com](http://hellogiggles.com/) as a source!</sub>

Comment: She had the HP Encyclopedia planned possibly as early as 2000, and her plans for that eventually became Pottermore. http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/0500-aol-umkc.html

Comment: @Skooba -- True, but my *guess* is some of Pottermore's information is newly written material. I could certainly be wrong. J.K. Rowling just seems like she's enjoying writing more Potter material -- above and beyond the 10 original canon books, I mean. :)

Comment: All of Jo's Pottermore writings are from the encylopedia she wrote shortly after finishing the books, besides for the series of writings "Magic in North America" which was written as a tie-in to the upcoming movie.

Comment: I seriously wonder what's the point in this Quest some people are following, to find each and every tiny mistake in the world created by Rowling. Okay, it's not perfect, but it's fantastic and wondrous.. it's like eating a cake searching for a crumb that taste bad.

Comment: @JustPassingBy - The purpose of fandom is to investigate the world created by the writer in order to gain a greater understanding and enjoyment in that world. That includes nitpicking.

Comment: @Valorum Yeah, but there's always the danger of it becoming excessive and pedantic, eliciting a "William Shatner" response. ;-)

Comment: @JustPassingBy - If we didn't nitpick, there'd be no SFF:SE :-)

Answer (score 20):

Given that the article doesn't *specifically* state that the conference was held in Washington **D.C.** (it refers to Washington four times, but never indicates a state), it must be at least *conceivable* that the headquarters were actually based in one of the other seven Washingtons that existed at the time, for example [Washington, Virginia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington,_Virginia) which was founded in 1749 or [Washington, North Carolina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington,_North_Carolina) which was formally established as a town in 1776, one year before the Washington Conference was held.

Similarly, the MACUSA was undoubtedly founded with a different name (MAC) then retitled as the MAC(USA) on the creation of the USA.

Comment: Washington D.C. is not a state; it is a federal district, just as an FYI. Williamsburg, Virginia, points to Washington DC on Mapquest. The actual [Pottermore article](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/macusa) notes that MACUSA relocated from its original locale in the Appalachian Mountains to Williamsburg, Virginia, in 1760; Williamsburg is only 152 miles south of what became Washington DC. It seems logical that "Washington" refers to Washington DC, especially with MACUSA being located previously in Virginia.

Comment: @slytherincess - Washington, Virginia is even closer :-) and as a bonus, it *actually existed* at the time of the conference.

Comment: While I don't think "Washington" refers to any city other than Washington DC, I considered a *teeny tiny* argument for Washington state, only because the MACUSA article mentions the Sasquatch (AKA Bigfoot), a supernatural creature seen -- ostensibly -- in the U.S.'s Pacific-Northwest region. Of course during that timeframe Washington state was not a state, so I don't think the Sasquatch theory quite works.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I meant to say Washington, Virginia (points to what is today Washington DC). :)

Comment: @Slytherincess - Their town website says that they occasionally get lost tourists with cheap GPS's :-)

Comment: @slytherincess - The article also doesn't say that the Washington it's referring to is **a city**. Since the wizarding world cup was held in a field, and given the existence of enlargement charms, a small town could theoretically suffice for a wizard HQ

Comment: Let us never be caught with cheap GPS devices! Yes, I realize the article doesn't explicitly say Washington as a city; I just think, logically and logistically, it *does* refer to Washington DC. That's my story, and I'm sticking to it! :)

Comment: @Slytherincess Granted, I am not a full believer of this answer either. I work in Washington, Pennsylvania, a city of 15,000. It is also located in Washington County (the first to be named such).

Comment: Today I learned that 3 of the current Washingtons aren't named after George Washington. They're named after Washington in England.

Comment: @Valorum - We (many of us, anyhow) love the UK, and I personally find it unsurprising that towns in the US are named after British persons, places, and/or things! Washington and Jefferson, in particular, seem to be popular names for towns and/or counties. In fact, there's both a Jefferson County and a Washington County in my state, Colorado  I suspect, as Colorado was not made a state until 1876, that our Washington County is named after George Washington, but I didn't research it, so I could be wrong. </OT comment> :)

Comment: @Slytherincess - An American colleague of mine was astounded to learn that New York was named after the nearby city of York. He'd lived in the Big Apple his entire life and literally never thought about where the word "new" fit into the history of the city.

Comment: Wait, does that mean that "New England" was named that by British settlers who felt that it might be an updated version of the place they just left??? _Mind Blown..._

Comment: @FreeMan - Never forget that America was founded by people who thought that the established church in the 17th Century (complete with occasional witch-burnings)  was just **too damned liberal.**

Answer (score 1):

IMHO The Magical Congress USA was founded in 1693 using some different name and renamed about a century later.  Maybe it was originally called Magical Congress of British America, or MACOBA, for example.

And maybe the Magical Congress of the Western Hemisphere (MACWH), or whatever it was called, met in the swampy region that later became Washington DC in 1777 and liked the region and decided to use magic on the founding fathers to make sure that region would eventually be selected as the federal district of the new country and they would have convenient access to use magic on the country's leaders whenever necessary.