# Is the MACUSA president elected?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts

Is the Wizard POTUS elected to a 4 year term like the No-Maj one? If so, can he/she be reelected?

Comment: Also, is there a wizard VP?

Comment: There's no indication of term limits, nor a VP as far as I can tell

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Seraphina Picquery was certainly *elected* to the position, at least according to the film's accompanying factbook [Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: Magical Movie Handbook.](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Magical-Movie-Handbook-Fantastic-Beasts/dp/1338116835)

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>Seraphina's charisma and leadership skills made her a natural to climb
> the political ladder of MACUSA. She reached its highest rung when her
> fellow wizards elected her as President of the organization.</sup></sub>

Comment: This only confirms that the *last* president of the MACUSA was elected, hundreds of years after Jackson’s term of office.

Comment: @Adamant - True, but I suspect the *historical* basis for the MACUSA government is liable to be of less interest than the characters we see in the film.

Comment: Yes, I would suspect that if the first *and* last president were elected that one's in middle bit were as well.

Comment: @Skooba - Go tell the [Romans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_emperor).

Comment: @Valorum Good point... doesn't change either of our answers though!

Answer (score 17):

**Yes, Presidents (and all representatives) were elected.**

> MACUSA was modeled on the Wizards’ Council of Great Britain, which predated the Ministry of Magic. **Representatives from magical communities all over North America were elected to MACUSA** to create laws that both policed and protected American wizardkind.
>
> ...
>
> The first President of MACUSA was Josiah Jackson, a warlike wizard who was **voted into post** by his fellow representatives because he was considered tough enough to deal with the difficulties of the post-Salem Witch Trials era.
>
> *[The Magical Congress of the United States of America (MACUSA)
> By J.K. Rowling](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/macusa)*

No word on term limits or vice presidents though...

Comment: This only confirms that the *first* president of the MACUSA was elected, hundreds of years before Picquery's term of office.

Comment: It would've been hilarious had this answer been given by @Adamant

Comment: Surely JK Rowling wouldn't use the term USA when describing an epoch almost a hundred years before the declaration of independence, right?

Comment: This is a good point and raises an interesting question about what happens when canon conflicts with history. Regardless of the fact that HP is fiction, it tries to fit in with non-fictional history. A body created in the late 1600s would not have used the term USA, since that only came about in the late 1700s (early 1776 in a letter to Lt.Col. Joseph Reed).

Comment: @Dancrumb America was still the name of the continent.  It had states in it.  If the magical congress was united over said states, it might call itself the united magical congress of the states of america, or the magical congress of the united states of america.  Then, when a set of states in the americas breaks off from britian, they might suggest "united states of america" to the no-maj.  Or maybe the name changed.

Comment: @Dancrumb [I thought the same exact thing](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142579/how-could-macusa-exist-in-1693-or-be-in-washington-in-1777)

Comment: @Yakk While the America name floated around for a while... there were no states, only colonies and territories until the Revolution.