# Where did Hagrid and Madame Maxime find the giants?

Tags: harry-potter, hagrid

Hagrid, together with Madame Maxime, went on a quest to find giants and win them over.

> "Ran inter a couple o’ mad trolls on the Polish border an’ I had a sligh’ disagreement with a vampire in a pub in Minsk, bu’ apart from tha’ couldn’t’a bin smoother."

They visited Dijon in France, had some problems with trolls at the Polish border, met a vampire in Minsk and finally arrived at the mountainous place.

> "An' then we reached the place, an' we started trekkin' up **through the mountains**, lookin' fer signs of 'em..."

They passed the Alps, the Carpathians seemed to be off their course, there are no mountains in the vicinity of Minsk (Belarus [doesn't strike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dzyarzhynskaya_Hara) as a mountainous country).

[image]

Where did they go? Are there any hints I missed in the story?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it could literally be anywhere in Europe/Eurasia with mountains. After they gave *"the berk tailin’ [them] the slip"* they used magic to move around, starting in Dijon, the Poland, then Minsk. What's the limit of apparition?

Comment: JKR probably isn't very good at geography [either](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/143313/31394) ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor - [Seems like she isn't](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/140363/what-is-jk-rowling-bad-at)

Comment: For the record, there area considerable number of mountains with a few minutes drive of Minsk. [They're not very high though](https://peakvisor.com/adm/minsk-region.html)

Comment: @Valorum Yes, they are rather low... A giant's snoring can't cause an avalanche there. Also, it feels like she had a particular place in mind - *"They was in this dip between four **pretty high** mountains, see, beside a mountain lake"*

Comment: @Valorum Not sure about the limitation of apparition (depends, I guess, on your magical skill and how vividly you can imagine the destination), but they couldn't use it much (or at all) since they were afraid they might've been followed

Comment: @AndrewTobilko - The text would suggest they used it extensively after losing their tail, right up to the point where they reached the supposed mountains, which could literally be anywhere.

Comment: Hagrid could have apparated to the mountains and then started walking around on foot looking for giants. If he apparated, then the mountains could be anywhere on the Eurasian continent.